# Naming a "core" Assembly

Tags: .net

I know that this is somewhat subjective, but I wonder if there is a generally accepted standard for naming assemblies which contain some "core" functions.

Let's say you got a larger Projects, with Assemblies like

- Company.Product.WebControls.dll
- Company.Product.Net.dll
- Company.Product.UserPages.dll

and you have a Bunch of "Core" classes, like the Global Error Handler, the global Logging functionality etc.

How would such an assembly generally named? Here are some things I had in mind:

- Company.Product.dll
- Company.Product.Core.dll
- Company.Product.Global.dll
- Company.Product.Administration.dll

Now, while "just pick one and go on" will not cause Armageddon, I'd still like to know if there is an "accepted" way to name those assemblies.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

With .Net this is relatively easy to change, so I'd go with convenience.

Fewer, larger, assemblies compile quicker than many small ones, so I'd start with your 'core' stuff as a namespace inside Company.Product.dll, and split it out later if you need to.

Answer (score 38):

All these "root", "core", "common" and so on, are **probably not the best naming-conventions**.

Common stuff should lie in the root namespace, like in .NET, `string`, `int` and other things that are "core" or "common" lies in the root `System`-namespace.

**Don't use namespaces to more easily collapse your folders in Visual Studio**, but structure it after **what it contains and what it's used for**.

`System.Security` contains common security-things that, for example `System.Xml` doesn't need to know about, unless you want that functionality explicitly.

`System.Security.Cryptography`is a sub-namespace. Cryptography is security, but **security is not explicitly cryptography**.

In this way `System.Security.Cryptography` has **full insight into it's parent namespace** and can **implictly use all classes inside** of its parent.

I would say `System.Core.dll` was a **slip-up on Microsoft's side**. They must have ran out of ideas or DLL-names.

**Update**: MSDN has a somewhat updated [article that tries to explain Microsoft's thinking on the subject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973231.aspx#assenamesp_topic5).

Comment: Just to note, .NET BCL **does** have System.Core.dll **assembly** but it **does not** have System.Core **namespace**. So from your perspective MS did everything right.

Comment: @Oybek Yeah, it should be "they must have ran out of ideas or DLL-names".

Comment: "System.Security.Cryptography is a sub-namespace." "System.Security.Cryptography... can implicitly use all classes inside of its parent" - these statements are incorrect. There is no such thing as a "sub-namespace." Namespaces are just strings of characters and .NET doesn't doesn't check to see if one namespace name is a substring of another. Now the .NET architects may have architected System.Security.Cryptography so that it can access all System.Security classes, but that doesn't happen implicitly.

Answer (score 11):

I typically like to have names which describe what is inside each assembly.

You see, if you name something as .Core, then on a large team, it can grow very quickly as people would consider putting very common thing in that assembly.

So, I think that there shouldn't really be one core assembly.

Comment: I don't have a problem with there being a "Core" assembly per se, but you are right in saying it can quickly become a dumping ground for all kinds of code when working on a large team.

Answer (score 5):

I've used .Core, .Framework, and .Common.

Answer (score 5):

We use this model:

- Company.Core.dll
- Company.WinControls.dll
- Company.WebControls.dll
- Company.Product.Core.dll
- Company.Product.WinControls.dll
- Company.Product.WebControls.dll

etc.

Answer (score 2):

i always do .Core.dll.

Answer (score 2):

The one I use most common and seem to love because I don't see other people use it is `Root`

I'll generally do

```
CompanyName.Root
```

or

```
SomethingMeaningfulToMe.Root
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those it depends questions. If its your code and you work on a small team I would use any naming convention that makes sense to you.  I have seen however in large code bases namespaces allow ways for downstream developers to discover functionality without the need of documentation or training. we use the model. standardizing the namespaces made it easier for developers to move team to team.

BussinessName.Division.Layer

Answer (score 0):

i also used .Core, especially for the .dll

Its all a matter of taste imo, if the root namespace is a company name, i feel .Core/framework/common is more descriptive than just the company name.

However if you're working on something like a opensource project where the name of the dll/namespace is also the name of the project, .Core/../ might be a little redundant.

There are many example in the .net framework and other microsoft libraries where both conventions are used. there is a System.dll and a System.Core.dll for example :)

Answer (score 0):

Core is very meaningful and easy to understand naming convention and it does not conflict with any .net framework namespace so it is very good practice.

I strongley recomend to encapsulate in each assembly the service it suppose to provide to the application that uses it and not to mix different function domains in one assembly.

We are using

```
CSG.Core
CSG.Data
CSG.Services
...
```

In the Core we are including classes that are likely to be used in all our products: Logging, Collection Extensions, Generics, Configuration extensions, Security, Validation, etc.

Although comiling many assemblies is slower than fewer and larger assembly, it optimizes your deployment because you deploy only classes that are used by your system and not contains many classes that not used just because you wanted to save compile time.

When you name your namespaces I am strongly recomends to **avoid repeating the same word in different level of the namespace**. For example, avoid the following:

```
YourCompany.Core
YourCompany.YourProduct.Core
```

Either put the core in the YourCompany or in Myproduct but not in both. It can be very confusing if for example your using looks like:
    using YourCompany;
    using YourCompany.YourProduct;

When you will type Core.SomeClass it will be very confusing where this class came from and in case you have 2 classes with the same name it will cause a conflict.